# Erro no 'this' em uma função typescript

Tags: typescript

Estou com erro na função abaixo:

```
export const throttle = (func: Function, limit: number) => {
   let inThrottle: boolean;
   return function () {
      const args = arguments;
      const context = this;
      if (!inThrottle) {
         func.apply(context, args);
         inThrottle = true;
         setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit);
      }
   }
}
```

Não consigo passar o `this` para a `const` `context` aparece o seguinte erro:

> [ts] 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a
>   type annotation.

Comment: Nós não escrevemos [RESOLVIDO] no título, como você mesmo chegou a solução, terá que marcar a sua resposta como resposta certa. Pode ser que tenha que esperar 48 horas para liberar essa opção para você

Comment: Tentei fazer isso porém sem sucesso.
Aparece a seguinte mensagem: Você não pode votar no seu post

Answer (score 2):

*********SOLUÇÃO***************

```
export const throttle = (func: Function, limit: number) => { 
   let inThrottle: boolean; 
   return function () { 
      const args = arguments; 
      if (!inThrottle) { 
         func.apply(null, args); 
         inThrottle = true; 
         setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit); 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Removi o `context`, e passei null para a função dentro do `apply`

Answer (score 0):

O problema está sendo causado por conta de seu this não estar vinculado a um objeto, mas ele pode representar qualquer coisa nesse contexto. Se você deseja dar a possibilidade de haver um this vinculado a função você deve esperar que o escopo seja passado por argumento.

```
export const throttle = (func: Function, limit: number, scope: Object = null) => { 
   let inThrottle: boolean; 
   return function () { 
      const args = arguments; 
      if (!inThrottle) { 
         func.apply(scope, args); 
         inThrottle = true; 
         setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit); 
      } 
   } 
}
```